# Wpf - Updating list following user control event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, user-controls

I have a WrapPanel in MainWindow.xaml that is being populated with (PlayerCard) User Control Children. These user controls individually display 'Player.cs' Properties. Each User Control has a delete button that allows me to remove one of the PlayerCards in the WrapPanel.

I also have a list of player objects called 'playerList' located in my MainWindow.xaml.cs that I use to write/read from an xml file every time a User Control is created.

What I am stuck on is how to modify my playerList in MainWindow while clicking on my delete button within my PlayerCard user control. How can I alert MainWindow that this user control is being removed? It seems like firing an event would be appropriate, but I am not sure how.

Player.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace BaseballLinker.Objects
{
    public class Player
    {
        [XmlElement("Player Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("MLB Link")]
        public string mlb { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("MiLB Link")]
        public string milb { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ESPN Link")]
        public string espn { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Baseball Referance Link")]
        public string baseballref { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Fangraphs Link")]
        public string fangraphs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BaseballLinker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1600" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/Background.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="77*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="14*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="71*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Add Player" FontSize="35" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="Name" Margin="0,10" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="Name_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,-15" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="MLB" Margin="0,35" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="MLB_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="MLB" Margin="0,-35" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="MiLB" Margin="0,25" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="MiLB_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="MiLB" Margin="0,-30" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="ESPN" Margin="0,25" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="ESPN_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ESPN" Margin="0,-30" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="BRef" Margin="0,25" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="BRef_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Baseball Referance" Margin="0,-30" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="FG" Margin="0,25" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" GotKeyboardFocus="FG_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Fangraphs" Margin="0,-30" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>

                <Button x:Name="Add" Margin="0,30" Height="35" Width="125" Content="Add Player" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Add_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="16*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <WrapPanel x:Name="PlayerCardList" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using BaseballLinker.Objects;
using BaseballLinker.User_Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace BaseballLinker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            InitializeComponent();

            loadPlayerList();
            populatePanel();

            this.Name.Focus();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Player> playerList;
        public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayerList
        {
            get { return playerList; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("playerList");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Name.Text != "")
            {
                var playerCard = new PlayerCard(Name.Text, MLB.Text, MiLB.Text, ESPN.Text, BRef.Text, FG.Text);

                PlayerCardList.Children.Add(playerCard);

                //Add Player Object To PlayerList
                Player p = new Player { name = Name.Text, 
                    mlb = MLB.Text, 
                    milb = MiLB.Text, 
                    espn = ESPN.Text, 
                    baseballref = BRef.Text, 
                    fangraphs = FG.Text };

                playerList.Add(p);

                App.SerializeToXML(playerList);

                clearFields();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A name is required.");
                Name.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void clearFields()
        {
            Name.Clear();
            MLB.Clear();
            MiLB.Clear();
            ESPN.Clear();
            BRef.Clear();
            FG.Clear();
            Name.Focus();
        }

        public void loadPlayerList()
        {
            try
            {
                playerList = App.DeserializeFromXML();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                playerList = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
            }
        }

        public void populatePanel()
        {
            foreach (Player p in playerList)
            {
                var playerCard = new PlayerCard(p.name, p.mlb, p.milb, p.espn, p.baseballref, p.fangraphs);

                PlayerCardList.Children.Add(playerCard);
            }
        }

        private void Name_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }

        private void MLB_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }

        private void MiLB_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }

        private void ESPN_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }

        private void BRef_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }

        private void FG_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerCard.xaml (User Control)

```
<UserControl x:Class="BaseballLinker.User_Controls.PlayerCard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="225" d:DesignWidth="200" Height="225" Width="200">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Margin="5">
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="31" />
            <RowDefinition Height="18*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="18*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="18*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Grid.Column="1" Width="25" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="5" Click="DeleteButton_Click" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PlayerName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

            <Button x:Name="MLBButton" Content="MLB" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="MLBButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="MiLBButton" Content="MiLB" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="MiLBButton_Click" />

            <Button x:Name="ESPNButton" Content="ESPN" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ESPNButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="BRButton" Content="BRef" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="BRButton_Click" />

            <Button x:Name="FGButton" Content="Fangraphs" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="FGButton_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

PlayerCard.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BaseballLinker.User_Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PlayerCard.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PlayerCard : UserControl
    {
        private string mlbURL;
        private string milbURL;
        private string espnURL;
        private string baseballRefURL;
        private string fangraphsURL;

        public PlayerCard(string name, string mlb, string milb, string espn, string baseballRef, string fangraphs)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PlayerName.Text = name;

            //Check if URLs are empty & modify button state.
            mlbURL = linkCheck(mlb, MLBButton);
            milbURL = linkCheck(milb, MiLBButton);
            espnURL = linkCheck(espn, ESPNButton);
            baseballRefURL = linkCheck(baseballRef, BRButton);
            fangraphsURL = linkCheck(fangraphs, FGButton);
        }

        private string linkCheck(string site, UIElement button)
        {
            if (site != "")
            {
                button.IsEnabled = true;
            }

            return site;
        }

        private void ESPNButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(espnURL);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid URL");
            }
        }

        private void MLBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(mlbURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid URL");
            }
        }

        private void MiLBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(milbURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid URL");
            }
        }

        private void BRButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(baseballRefURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid URL");
            }
        }

        private void FGButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(fangraphsURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid URL");
            }
        }

        private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are a newbie in wpf and c#, why you dont use biinding and put the player and player card in your model class, there you implement your NotifyPropertyChanged event and every thing work well. If you need some help just share your Xaml

Comment: I am a newbie in both. I'm currently not using any bindings just because I was unsure how to implement it. I'm also not sure about adding the player card user control to my player class.

Comment: I added my xaml files, I appreciate any advice for sure.

Comment: Would it be recommended using a ListBox control (or something of that nature) and have it wrapped inside of a datatemplate and bound from my model class? I was just unsure how to do things like modifying button states doing it this way. I really could use a tip on how to setup my model class for binding this list of players.

Comment: If you could upload your code and send me a link to see what i can do for u coz i found it hard to fix it, Actually, i found many thing weird such palyer model and how  you fill your playercard... it will be better if you give me your wall code and i will help you maybe we could fix an good conception

Comment: I will replace it with my wall of code for each file. My player card is being filled in the code behind as the info is being passed in through the constructor. It isn't the correct way to do it, its just the simplest way I knew how.

Comment: Alright, I added the full wall of code for Player.cs Model, PlayerCard.xaml, PlayerCard.xaml.cs, Mainwindow.xaml & MainWindow.xaml.cs. Here is a screen shot of what it looks like and you can more clearly see the intention of the code: http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1094/bd9q.png. Each player card has 5 buttons which launch a web browser to the given URLs entered in the form on the left.

Comment: Where would you recommend I upload this code to? I would still gladly send you a link to download it.